# Is calling a view function always free from outside of contract?

Tags: gas, view

In the following generalised code example, would `myMethod` still be free (no gas cost) to call from outside the contract? Even if it does a series of operations including `abi.encodePacked()`?

```
contract A{
    struct Data{
        uint8 num;
        bool include;
    }
    mapping (address => Data) dataMap;

    /*
        more functions
    */

    function myMethod() public view returns (string){
        string[2] memory array = ['a', 'b'];
        if(dataMap[msg.sender].include){
            return string(abi.encodePacked(array[dataMap[msg.sender].num], 'c'))
        }
        return array[dataMap[msg.sender].num];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always free to call the view function outside the contract. However, they do cost gas when you call it inside a transaction.

Comment: thank you for the answer.  imagine a function that made 50 keccak256(abi.encodePacked('string calls')) internally but didn't alter account storage.  Presumably those are calculations the EVM needs to process(?).  Are those not costly calculations needed to be accounted for?

Comment: Afaik, the calculations are being made on your local and the chain is only being used for reading data.